# Simple forward converter - strange demagnetisation

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, forward

I am trying to build a simple forward converter. After MOSFET turns off I am demagnetising to 100 µF cap on secondary side. There is about 1 µs core doing nothing and after that demagnetisation starts as expected. What is that 1 µs time (both side of transformer are completely disconnected during this time)?

Secondary voltage of transformer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit:
Below is Voltage across primary without demagnetising to 100 µF but demagnetising using 1 kΩ across primary instead (flyback)(discontinous mode) (100 Ω, 100 µF, D3 are removed). See flyback is too rounded. Cannot be the core too slow? I do not have datasheet.

[image]

Comment: that solder flux residue doesn't look good. Are you using electronics solder? Or by chance plumbing / pipe solder?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I used this small pcb “pads” so many times so flux gets dark. But soldering joints should be ok ( just looks terrible).

Comment: the flux could be shorting the connections

Comment: What diode types?

Comment: @TimWilliams D1 is FR107 and the others 1n4007.

Comment: What's the primary waveform look like?

Comment: @TimWilliams
Almost the same. The 1us part in waveform is also there.

Comment: How about the inductor node (between D1, D2, 10u)?

Comment: @TimWilliams This one is very nice. Commutation from D1 to D2 after mosfet turns off works perfect.

Comment: `What is that 1us time` <-- I don't understand what this question means because you seem to know what it is when you say: `(both side of transformer are completely disconnected during this time)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Pls see edits I found out.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's D1 reverse recovery.

It definitely looks weird in the first waveform.  It seems clearer in the second.  I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but it seems likely it has to do with the very low magnetizing current.

[FR107](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/ds26001.pdf)

[image]

It's a "fast" rectifier in that it's not the couple µs a 1N4007 might take to turn off, but it's not *fast* in the modern sense.

At these currents, you could try a 1N914/1N4148 or similar, any little glass-body diode really (just make sure it's not a zener); just beware, when you turn up the duty cycle, it's not likely to handle full load current here, heh.

You can also try schottky, for which any medium-power signal type will do (BAT85, BAT54, etc.), and proper rectifiers (B, SB, MBR, etc., preferably low numbers like 0540, 130, 140, 160, etc., i.e. ≤1A, ≥30V types), the capacitance will be dominant but maybe the resulting waveform will be more obvious as well.

Did you take any measurements on the core, or transformer?  If it's ferrite, likely A<sub>L</sub> is >1 µH/t<sup>2</sup>, so 50 t is a whopping 2.5 mH or more.  At (5 V)(13 µs)(50 t) / (60 t) = 54 µWb, 2.5 mH only draws (divide by L) 21.7 mA.  This is quite low current to force D1's recovery, hence the longer than specified duration.

Nice winding, by the way -- evenly distributed, tightly interleaved (hard not to on a toroid, really), you can see from the ringing transient at turn-off that leakage inductance is quite small.  (The ringing is mostly on the primary side, MOSFET drain capacitance ringing with leakage while D1 and D2 momentarily hold the secondary at a low impedance.)

Leakage inductance has to do with the space between primary and secondary windings; with them closely overlapped/interleaved like this, inductance is nice and low.  You will find, for layered windings (say, if you take apart some transformers using a bobbin), it's tempting to wind many turns in a block, for each primary and secondary, but this increases the distance between windings and thus the leakage.

Setting up to measure basic device properties may be illustrative:

For diode recovery, simply wiring it in series with a load resistor, and running that from a square-wave generator (bipolar voltage), gives you some idea about recovery time.  It's not perfect (the test current from a signal generator is quite low (50 Ω source), and capacitance plays a relatively large role in the measurement), but like I said, gives some idea.

There are two tests in common use for diodes: the current-limited mode shown in this datasheet, and a current-ramp waveform more representative of power converter service.  What they tested here, is basically the signal generator scheme, but with a voltage source, and a resistor small enough to give the currents shown.

(For transformer leakage: simply measure inductance of one winding, with the other winding shorted.)

Cheers!